# Safari input type="number" and pattern does not prevent letter entry

Tags: html, reactjs, safari, redux-form

does not work for safari browser while running on chrome. I also tried things like  that I found as a result of my research, but I could not ensure that numbers can be entered alone in safari.

I use Redux-form. Field component;

```
<Field
              name={name}
              component={renderFieldInput}
              type={type}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              isDisabled={isDisabled}
              maxLength={maxLength}
              min={min}
              max={max}
            />
```

renderFieldInput component;

```
const renderFieldInput = ({
  input, maxLength, min, max, label, placeholder, type, mask, isDisabled, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
    <div className="form__form-group-input-wrap">
      <input {...input} placeholder={placeholder} type={type} disabled={isDisabled} maxLength={maxLength} min={min} max={max} mask="[0-9]*" pattern="[0-9]*" inputMode="numeric" />
      {touched && error && <span className="form__form-group-error">{error}</span>}
    </div>
);
```

I added the pattern = "[0-9] *" inputMode = "numeric" parts here to try but it didn't work.

Any help.

Comment: have you checked if safari supports those functions?

Comment: The pattern function is supported after Safari 10.1 version. (https://caniuse.com/input-pattern)